# How do i set the controls attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I am creating buttons and add them to a table that i want to add onto a page:

```
    void MyButtonTable()
{

    TableRow myTableRow = new TableRow();

    foreach (var item in buttons)
    {
        TableCell myTableCell = new TableCell();
        myTableCell.Controls.Add(item);
        myTableRow.Cells.Add(myTableCell);

    }
    HtmlForm html = new HtmlForm();

   Table2.Rows.Add(myTableRow);
   Table2.BorderWidth = 1;
   Table2.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
   html.Controls.Add(Table2);
   Page.Controls.Add(html);
}
```

I need to add it through htmlForm and add it to the page..instead of adding the table straight to the page..
(i get Control 'ctl02' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.)
but when i add html, i want to cancel the run at attribute..to prevent this exception from being generated:

```
A page can have only one server-side Form tag
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the table inside the existing `<form runat="server">`.

As the error message states, you cannot have to server-side `<form>`s.

Comment: true. But if i put the table inside form run at.. which it is in by the way, it tells me that the buttons are not inside the form... :( I have a form1 object in my master page. have you got an idea how i can reach it. if i could i could put my buttons in that form,,preventing the exception

Comment: If you're in a content page, you can add the control to a `ContentPlaceHolder` inside the `<form>`

Comment: How do i add it? i cant add a single button to the page..without the following exception being thrown:Control 'ctl172' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: Add it to any control inside the `<form>`

Comment: I did to Table2:        <asp:Table ID="Table2" runat="server">
        </asp:Table> ..it is inside form tags..still throws same exception. It doesnt let me add a single control to the page... without that exception being thrown

Comment: Is there a tool in ajax which i could use to create a page index bar?

Comment: I haven't the faintest idea what you mean.